# Java ship keystore with application

Tags: java, keystore

I am making an application which uses `Logback` and `SSL` to log to my log server however its a massive inconvenience to sort out the `keystore` on each internal server which requires logging access to the server.

logback enables you to specify a key store in this manner:

```
  <appender name="name" 
      <!-- Enable SSL and use a different truststore -->
      <ssl>
          <trustStore>
              <location>classpath:server.truststore</location>
              <password>${server.truststore.password}</password>
          </trustStore>
      </ssl>
  </appender>
```

Which I would like to make it so I can add the keystore (containing the keys) to the application and tell logback that my keystore is in this location e.g.

```
<appender name="name" 
          <!-- Enable SSL and use a different truststore -->
          <ssl>
              <trustStore>
                  <location>project-root/some/path</location>
                  <password>${server.truststore.password}</password>
              </trustStore>
          </ssl>
      </appender>
```

How do you actually achieve this? I've looked online a fair bit and I'm not fully understanding how to achieve this. I've read there is a `jks` format or something?

I understand `keystores` (somewhat) I just don't understand how to create a separate `keystore` and 'bundle' it with my project.

For those who may have security worries, this application is only used on internal servers and is never publicly available.

Comment: `classpath:server.truststore` sounds like the file is already being looked up as a classpath resource, and your application's JAR or WAR or whatever is already on the classpath.  Have you tried just putting the file in the root package directory within your application?